# Making a SPA using vue but having some trouble

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I am using Larvel (latest version) and I am attempting to make a SPA using vuejs. I followed a SPA tutorial in the laracast episodes about vue js. However, i am having a little bit of trouble. I think im doing something wrong in the routes.js file because in the tutorial it says to make the component be require(./views/home) but the require function is not being 
resolved.

The problem is that on the page the router-link tag is not being compiled to an anchor tag

Boostrap.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

window.axios = axios;
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Router.js

```
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

      let routes = [
      {
          path:'/',
          component: require('./views/home')
      }];

      export default new VueRouter({
         routes
      });
```

App.js

```
import './bootstrap';
import router from './routes'

new Vue({
     el: '#app',

    router
});
```

home.vue

```
<template>

    <section class="hero is-dark">
      <div class="hero-body">
            <div class="container">
             <h1 class="title">
                 Primary title
              </h1>
              <h2 class="subtitle">
                   Primary subtitle
                 </h2>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>

</template>


<script>
 export default {
       mounted() {
           console.log('Component mounted.')
       }
  }
</script>
```

nav

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>

    @include('partials.head')

<title>My App</title>
</head>
<body class="">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div id="app">
          <router-link to='/'>Home</router-link>
          <router-link to='/about'>About</router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@include('partials.footer')

</body>
</html>
```

Mix

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
```

Comment: Please post your #nav element... I seem to be missing that bit.

Comment: @DavidHeremans i added the app Layout which includes the "nav" elements

Comment: Your bootstrap.js says Vue.use(‘VueRouter’); I believe you need to use the imported variable and not a string literal.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @DavidHeremans, still did not fix my problem. In the browser it says that that router-link is an unregistered component

Comment: Did that fix your issue?

Comment: @DavidHeremans no

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161919/discussion-between-thatpurpleguy-and-david-heremans).

Comment: Never mind that fixed it i forgot to recompile

Comment: Brilliant.  I will add an answer then :-)

Answer (score 0):

When looking at your **bootstrap.js**, it seems you are doing `Vue.use(‘VueRouter’)`.  When calling the `use` method, you need to pass it the VueRouter object you imported, and not a string literal.